# multi dimensional ssas data cube month name display alphabetic order (apr,aug,dec) need to display financial order like (july,aug,sep..)

Tags: ssas, powerbi-desktop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZffy.png)I am using ssas multidimensional data cube. That multidimensional data cube uses in power bi desktop with live connection. Every thing works fine. But when i want to display month name according financial year (july, aug, Sept)they display (april, aug,dec) alphabetic order. But need to display according to financial year into power bi.Can any body help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbQxGrJVy5w&list=LLDdQWSt2mmHAF0AgewyJwKQ&index=4&t=704s

I followed this link.
Also power bi SSAS live connection does not allow to edit model pane.
SSAS Import connection allow to edit model pane.

Answer (score 0):

if your dataset includes month number as well then you can click on that particular col, go to modelling pane and then sort by month number.

Comment: I have passed financial month name, and financial month code by dimension hierarchy. But power bi ssas live connection sort by column is disabled in model pane that's why i can't  do it.